# Javascript: change onclick dynamically having "window.open"

Tags: javascript, onclick, window.open

I wanted to change the value of my onclick, I tried this but it doesn't work. Any help?

```
<a href='#' id='social' onClick="">click</a>
document.getElementById("social").onclick = "open_new_window('https://twitter.com/share?url=https%3A%2F%2F"+url+"&amp;via=iguestblogger&amp;text="+title+"');";
```

NOTE: `url`, `title` and `open_new_window()` are already defined and work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the value of `onclick` attribute, just bind the event.

```
document.getElementById("social").onclick = function() {
  open_new_window('https://twitter.com/share?url=https%3A%2F%2F'+url+'&amp;via=iguestblogger&amp;text='+title);
};
```

Comment: Hmmm - Not only did I fix the quote but I return false to stop the click from following the href AND I encode the title

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("social").onclick = function(){open_new_window('https://twitter.com/share?url=https%3A%2F%2F"+url+"&amp;via=iguestblogger&amp;text="+title+"');};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming url and title and function open_new_window was already defined earlier - also watch your quotes

```
<a href='#' id='social' >click</a>
<script>
document.getElementById("social").onclick = function()
  open_new_window("https://twitter.com/share?url=https%3A%2F%2F"+url+"&amp;via=iguestblogger&amp;text="+encodeURI(title));
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById("social").onclick = open_new_window('https://twitter.com/share?url=https%3A%2F%2F"+url+"&amp;via=iguestblogger&amp;text="+title+"');
```

Comment: In your code, `open_new_window` is called before the assignment, and its result is written to the `onclick` attribute. So, 1) `open_new_window` is unconditionally executed before the `onclick` changes (probably, during the page loading), not when the user clicks on the specific link; 2) Clicking on link will cause a javascript error, as `open_new_window` return value is probably not a function.

Comment: Compare `element.onclick = alert('Javascript has been processed');` and `element.onclick = function () { alert('Element has been clicked'); };`.